# jQuery Mobile: ui-page-active class remains on first page in webkit - displaying the current and previous pages

Tags: jquery-mobile, webkit

In webkit, jquery mobile is giving me issues.

I link to an internal page and when arriving upon that page, both '`<div data-role="page">`' elements have the ui-page-active class which makes both of them display. This is not the case with Firefox. Firefox correctly removes that class so that the first page's "page" is hidden.

I'm using jQuery 1.7.1,
jQuery Mobile 1.0,
jQuery default css theme,
Latest Safari, Chrome, Firefox versions.

It also does not work in the iPhone emulator.

Example:
http://chrispaul.ws/mobile.html

If you go directly to http://chrispaul.ws/weather.html or http://chrispaul.ws/deals.html then they display fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `data-rel="external"` attribute to the anchor tags. Worked for me.